# Selenium Fake the browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing

Is there a way to fake the browser type and version? For example, to run only the version of firefox, but the sites identified me as Opera, Safari, etc.?

I only found a solution with the substitution of the agent version in the header, but I know that it is possible to request the browser version via JavaScript.

Comment: You can safely omit [java] tag from your question as this is language agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but getting the browser version for e.g. any chromium based browser (Chromium, Google Chrome, Edge, Brave...) would typically involve calling "navigator.userAgent" and picking things up from there.

That said, you should be on the safe side if you can pass the (exposed) user agent to selenium at startup.